# Host ARCore ancores longer than 24 hours

Tags: android, arcore

As far as we know ARCore session ancores host on Google servers only for 24 hours.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/arcore-cloud-anchors/#0

Is there way to expand this time or store them in other way?

Answer (score 1):

> Note: We’re currently developing persistent Cloud Anchors, which can be resolved for much longer. Before making the feature broadly available, we’re looking for more developers to help us explore and test persistent Cloud Anchors in real world apps at scale. See here if you’re interested.

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/overview-android#data_storage_and_access_limitations

Comment: 403 Forbidden in apply to early access form :D